# Difference between keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy and 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Can somebody please tell me the difference between loss calculators,`loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` and `loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` for CNN models.
`keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` is only compatible with the train label array shape, as `(60000,10)` for [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) data set, and `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` is compatible with the input shape `(60000,1)`. Why is it so ? And How does these two differ mathematically?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before, see the linked answer.